# How to make cscope display full file paths during search

Tags: linux, search, ide, ctags, cscope

When I search for a C symbol or global definition using `cscope`, it displays the file-names and line numbers. I would like to see the full file-paths so that I can jump to my arch specific file. For example, when searching for global definition of `__switch_to` on `cscope` build on Linux code-base, I get:

```
Global definition: __switch_to

  File         Line
0 process.c    297 struct task_struct *__switch_to(struct task_struct *prev,
1 switch_to.h   44 #define __switch_to(prev,next,last) do { \
2 process.c    202 struct task_struct *__switch_to(struct task_struct *old,
3 process.c    400 struct task_struct *__switch_to(struct task_struct *prev,
4 process_32.c 211 __switch_to(struct task_struct *prev, struct task_struct *next)
5 process.c     80 void *__switch_to(struct task_struct *from, struct task_struct *to)
6 process_32.c 248 __switch_to(struct task_struct *prev_p, struct task_struct *next_p)
7 process_64.c 272 __switch_to(struct task_struct *prev_p, struct task_struct *next_p)
```

Now, the file `process.c` is different for each `arch`. How to make `cscope` display the full file-paths?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run cscope with args -pn

> -pn    Display the last n file path components instead of the default (1). Use 0 not to display the file name at all.

Running with cscope -p4 and searching for global definition of __switch_to results in

```
Global definition: __switch_to

  File                           Line
0 arch/arm64/kernel/process.c    297 struct task_struct *__switch_to(struct task_struct *prev,
1 ia64/include/asm/switch_to.h    44 #define __switch_to(prev,next,last) do { \
2 arch/openrisc/kernel/process.c 202 struct task_struct *__switch_to(struct task_struct *old,
3 arch/powerpc/kernel/process.c  400 struct task_struct *__switch_to(struct task_struct *prev,
4 arch/sh/kernel/process_32.c    211 __switch_to(struct task_struct *prev, struct task_struct *next)
5 arch/um/kernel/process.c        80 void *__switch_to(struct task_struct *from, struct task_struct *to)
6 arch/x86/kernel/process_32.c   248 __switch_to(struct task_struct *prev_p, struct task_struct *next_p)
7 arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c   272 __switch_to(struct task_struct *prev_p, struct task_struct *next_p)
```