# How can cscope be used through script to find definitions?

Tags: c, linux, cscope

Is there any way cscope can be used in script to find global definitions? I am looking for options where I can validate the sizes of structures used while memory allocation. Instead of writing a program to find the definition on my own, I intend to use cscope to find the definition of the structure. Later I can parse through the definition and calculate the size of the structure. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Got this solution:

`cscope -d -L1<symbol>`

-L option does a single search with line-oriented output when used with the -num pattern option. num is the menu option starting from 0. So '1' stands for global definition menu option
-d options means not to build index again.

Answer (score 0):

[How to find struct member uses with cscope and ignore local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190955/how-to-find-struct-member-uses-with-cscope)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/FE8DRbDtNb8

Does this helps

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: No. first link is to differentiate local and structure in cscope and second link is searching struct definition in same file. Neither is the solution for my query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928705/how-to-make-cscope-display-full-file-paths-during-search this has a pointer towards global definitions

Comment: Sorry, that is still not the solution. However, I found this interim solution: `cscope -d -L1<symbol>` which provides with filename,line number and line of the definition of the symbol.